# Why is the following _.map function returning nothing?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I created a function to find objects:

**store.js**

```
store.find = () => {
  const query = new Parse.Query(Document)
  return query.find()
}
```

That I'm using like this (and assigning the value to `this.documents`):

**main.js**

```
store.find().then((results) => {
  this.documents = _.map(results, (result) => {
    return result.toJSON()
  })
})
```

It works. But the `store.find().then( ...)` part is repeated many times in `main.js` so I turned it into a function:

**store.js**

```
store.fetch = (documents) => {
  return store.find().then((results) => {
    documents = _.map(results, (result) => {
      return result.toJSON()
    })

  })
}
```

Which I use like this:

**main.js**

```
store.fetch(this.documents)
```

But nothing is being assigned to `this.documents` and there are no error messages. What's could be the problem?

*NOTE:* `this.documents` is an array of objects. Example:

```
[{
  title: this.title,
  content: this.content,
}, ...
```

*EDIT:*

I did this:

```
store.fetch = (documents) => {
  store.find().then((results) => {
    documents = _.map(results, (result) => {
      return result.toJSON()
    })
    console.log(documents)
  })
}
```

And `documents` is being assigned:

```
[Object, Object, Object, ...]
```

So I think it's just not assigning this array to `this.documents`. Maybe variables can't be arguments and be assigned with a value at the same time?

Comment: Well, you're not *returning* anything, you're merely assigning to `documents`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `this.documents` as an argument and attempting to modify that property inside the function. However, that can't work, because [Javascript does not have "pass by reference"](http://whatsthepointy.blogspot.com.es/2013/11/javascript-does-not-have-pass-by.html). Only "pass by value".

Instead, you can try passing the object and the property name separately:

```
store.fetch = (obj, prop) => {
  return store.find().then((results) => {
    obj[prop] = _.map(results, (result) => {
      return result.toJSON()
    })
  })
}
store.fetch(this, 'documents')
```

Comment: Hey, it worked. This is so weird, I'll check the link you posted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I still don't get why it doesn't work when `this` and `documents` are passed together, but they do when they are passed separately.

Comment: @alexchenco In order to assign a property you need both the object and the property name. You were trying to pass the property, but only its value is passed to the function, not the object you want it to belong to.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get your results in a `.then` block after `store.fetch(this.documents)`. And don't forget to store context

```
var self = this;
store.fetch(self.documents).then(function () {
    console.log(self.documents);
});
```

Or usign es6

```
store.fetch(this.documents).then(() => {
    console.log(this.documents);
});
```